# On Linux, could a process render another process's GUI?

Tags: linux, video, x11

I am writing a video player on Linux and I would like to separate it into 2 process :

A. decoder process
B. GUI

In this way, I could use different programming languages and when a problem happens, it's easier to know where is the problem.

The problem is, could process A render decoded pictures onto B's surface directly?  I don't want to use some IPC to send B these decoded data because that might be very inefficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [XEmbed](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html) specification, which allows you to embed one X11 window inside another, and they might be from different processes. This is what other media player frontends typically do.

Both GTK and [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qx11embedcontainer.html) support XEmbed.

Answer (score 4):

IPC (especially a Unix pipe) is much more efficient then you think and it is probably the right mechanism to use.

However, since you asked how to do it without IPC (and I parse this to mean without context switches and copies), you can simply create a shared memory segment between the two processes:

```
fd = shm_open("/my_shmem", O_RDWR| O_CREAT, S_IWUSR);
if(fd == -1) abort(); 
ftruncate(fd, SHMEM_SIZE); 
p = mmap(NULL, SHMEM_SIZE, PROT_WRITE |  PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 
if(p == MAP_FAILED) abort()
```

Now p has the address to a shared memory segment shared by the two (or more) processes.

Warning! the numeric value of p (virtual address of memory) might be different between the processes, so if you want to put a linked list in the shared memory for example, you'd have to use offsets.

Cheers,
gby

Answer (score 1):

Look at how mplayer and smplayer are implemented. mplayer decodes and shows the video, and smplayer is the (optional) GUI.